# Do modern calendars require anything more than `TZID` for timezone compatibility?

Tags: python, calendar, timezone, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am creating a `.ics` file using [icalendar](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt).

I am trying to be very thorough to ensure the best compatability across calendar clients.

In the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) for `ICS` (yes, I am being that thorough), the `VTIMEZONE` calendar component (`4.6.5 Time Zone Component`) takes both a required `TZID` and a set of optional `Standard Time` and `Daylight Saving Time` observances.

iCalendar has an undocumented function to create these components as `TimezoneStandard()` and `TimezoneDaylight()`, but are they really necessary for compatibility?

I would have thought that most modern calendars (e.g. Outlook, Google Cal, etc) would only require a `TZID` to determine daylight savings, etc. Is this correct?

If not, is there an easy library to determine the appropriate inputs (`TZOFFSETFROM`, `TZOFFSETTO` and the `RRULE`s)?

Comment: TimezoneStandard() is not part of the iCalendar spec... where are you getting this? They are needed though

Comment: Also, you are reading an outdated, obsolete spec. You want rfc5545, not rfc2445